# SQLite to MySQL strange error #1064

Tags: mysql, sqlite, phpmyadmin, migration, mysql-error-1064

I'm converting a SQLite database to MySQL so I can import it to PHPMyAdmin. 
This should be straightforward. I exported it to a dump, changed the autoincrements and changed all double quotes to backticks. This is what the start of the resulting file looks like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chars`;
CREATE TABLE chars(
                            charid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                            character TEXT
                    );
INSERT INTO `chars` VALUES(3,'a');
INSERT INTO `chars` VALUES(4,'b');
```

...
When trying to import to PHPMyAdmin it throws this error.

> ```
> Error
> SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE chars(
>
> charid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
> CHARACTER TEXT
> );
>
> MySQL said: 
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character TEXT
>                     )' at line 3
> ```

Is there too much space after the indented line? I left the "format" option as "SQL", left SQL compatibility mode as NONE and left "Do not use AUTO_INCREMENT for zero values" ticked. 
Its going to be used in a django web app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CHARACTER` is a [reserved word in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). I'm betting that is the reason.

Use either a different column name (preferred), or use backticks:

```
 `CHARACTER` TEXT
```

Comment: If possible, definitely change the name of the column... it just isn't worth the hassle if you can name it differently.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Turns out both "CHARACTER" and "CHAR" are reserved keywords in MySQL but not in SQLite.

Comment: @pekka SO needs an automated filter for detecting MySQL reserved words in questions - `CHARACTER, DESC` in particular.

Comment: @Michael yeah! Or a mechanism to close as localized more easily.